# Raspberry Pi server , Problems showing a table that is located in a seperate Html file

Tags: python, html, raspberry-pi

I have a web server on raspberry pi, but I want to show a table on the webpage but the table is stored in a separate folder on the raspberry pi.
We are using Flask (Python3) to run this server.
What is the best way for us to display the table in this separate local HTML file on my server?

We've been trying to figure this out but with no luck, it doesn't seem like this is the best way to go about showing an Updating table through HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Specify your HTML templates folder when you define your app:

```
template_dir="path/to/directory"
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder=template_dir)
```

Flask will look for HTML files within this specified directory.